# Cannot follow the same aggregate relationship twice: Cases

Tags: triggers, apex

Hello I have difficulty create a list/array in SELECT function Apex Trigger.

`Array`**List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = [SELECT Id,
(SELECT Id FROM Cases WHERE IsClosed = false) openCases,
(SELECT Id FROM Cases WHERE IsClosed = true) closedCases
FROM Contact
WHERE Id IN :contactIds];**

As "Cannot follow the same aggregate relationship twice: Cases"

Please
Thanks

Comment: I want to create a custom roll-up to count open and closed cases per each contact.